# Android getText from TokenAutoComplete library

Tags: android

i'm using `TokenAutoComplete` and i can not get text from this library after fill EditText by clicking on button. please help me to get data from it

Activity:

```
public class TokenActivity extends Activity  implements TokenCompleteTextView.TokenListener {
    ContactsCompletionView completionView;
    Person[] people;
    ArrayAdapter<Person> adapter;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.token);

        people = new Person[]{
                new Person("amanda Johnson", "amanda  example com"),
                new Person("terry Anderson", "terry  example com")
        };

        adapter = new ArrayAdapter<Person>(this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, people);

        completionView = (ContactsCompletionView)findViewById(R.id.searchView);
        completionView.setAdapter(adapter);

    }

    @Override
    public void onTokenAdded(Object token) {
        Log.e ( "------->", String.valueOf ( token ) );
    }

    @Override
    public void onTokenRemoved(Object token) {
        Log.e ( "------->>>", String.valueOf ( token ) );
    }
}
```

Comment: Did u try `personObj.getName();` ?

Comment: @SweetWisherツ no sir. i can not find any document about it and how to use

Comment: have u implemenetd [all these??](https://github.com/splitwise/TokenAutoComplete)

Comment: @SweetWisherツ yes i'm implemented that `public interface TokenListener `

Answer (score 0):

The objects in the completionView should be available from getObjects. Are you trying to get raw text out of it?